# Js->link append data instead of update

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I use CakePHP version 2.4.7

I use `Js` helper like this

```
$this->Js->link('+ Add file', array('action' => 'add_file'), array('update' => '#files'))
```

The problem is I want to append the `#files` content with the returned data instead of replace.

Please let me know if there is any work-around for this.

Answer (score 0):

It works on cake2.2.9. 
code:

```
echo $this->Form->button('+ Add file', array('id'=>'add_file','type'=>'button','class'=>'buttonStyle'));
$callback_code = 'var c_html = $("#click_update").html();$("#content_update").append(c_html);';
$request_code = $this->Js->request(
    array('action' => 'a', 'param'),
    array('async' => false, 'update' => '#click_update','complete' =>$callback_code)
);
$this->Js->get('#add_file')->event('click',$request_code);

----------
```

hope useful to you!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. `appendChild` doesn't work. I can't find `Js->request` on my CakePHP 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Js-Jquery-Helper-Append-Instead-of-Update-td3325344.html

Basically you need to make a small change to JqueryEngineHelper.php (for CakePHP 2.x) request function:

```
public function request($url, $options = array()) {
        $url = html_entity_decode($this->url($url), ENT_COMPAT, Configure::read('App.encoding'));
        $options = $this->_mapOptions('request', $options);
        if (isset($options['data']) && is_array($options['data'])) {
            $options['data'] = $this->_toQuerystring($options['data']);
        }
        $options['url'] = $url;
        if (isset($options['update'])) {
            $wrapCallbacks = isset($options['wrapCallbacks']) ? $options['wrapCallbacks'] : true;
            $success = '';
            if (isset($options['success']) && !empty($options['success'])) {
                $success .= $options['success'];
            }
```

/*add the following if block, adding the "position" option, if it's not set, set it to default "html" */

```
            if(!isset($options['position'])){
                $options['position'] = "html";
            }
```

/*and here's the changed part: replace the ".html(data) part with $options['position'] */

```
            $success .= $this->jQueryObject . '("' . $options['update'] . '").' . $options['position'] . '(data);';
            if (!$wrapCallbacks) {
                $success = 'function (data, textStatus) {' . $success . '}';
            }
            $options['dataType'] = 'html';
            $options['success'] = $success;
            unset($options['update']);
        }
        $callbacks = array('success', 'error', 'beforeSend', 'complete');
        if (!empty($options['dataExpression'])) {
            $callbacks[] = 'data';
            unset($options['dataExpression']);
        }
        $options = $this->_prepareCallbacks('request', $options);
        $options = $this->_parseOptions($options, $callbacks);
        return $this->jQueryObject . '.ajax({' . $options . '});';
    }
```

and in your View you can use the position option:

```
$this->Js->link('+ Add file', array(
    'action' => 'add_file'
  ), array(
    'update' => '#files',
    'position' => 'append'
));
```

Comment: Thanks raumus. I will check your answer later.